# Почему мой меш плоский и меняет позицию?

Tags: unity3d

**Перед стартом:** (Это базовый куб)

[image]

**После старта:** (Это должен быть глаз (то есть шар))

[image]

**Transform Wood Table:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Код:***

**IngredientAsset:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Ingredient", menuName = "Ingredient")]
public class IngredientAsset : ScriptableObject {

    public Mesh ingredientMesh;

}
```

**Ingredient:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Ingredient : MonoBehaviour {

    public IngredientAsset asset;
    


    public Ingredient (IngredientAsset a) {
        asset = a;
    }
    
    public bool HasIngrediend()
    {
        if (asset == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Mesh GetIngrediendMesh()
    {
        if (asset == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return asset.ingredientMesh;

    }


}
```

**TableBox:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TableBox : MonoBehaviour {

    public MeshFilter overlay;

    public IngredientAsset ingredient;
    public EquipmentAsset equipment;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        if (ingredient!=null) {
            overlay.mesh = ingredient.ingredientMesh;
        } else if (equipment != null) {
            overlay.mesh = equipment.equipmentMesh;
        }
    }
    
    public void Interact(IngredientAsset c, EquipmentAsset t, PlayerInteraction player)
    {
        player.SetIngredient(ingredient);
        ingredient = c;
        player.SetEquipment(equipment);
        equipment = t;
        
        if (equipment != null)
            overlay.mesh = equipment.equipmentMesh;
        else if (ingredient != null)
            overlay.mesh = ingredient.ingredientMesh;
        else
            overlay.mesh = null;
    }
}
```

**PlayerInteraction:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerInteraction : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject target;
    
    public KeyCode interactKey;

    
    [SerializeField]
    private IngredientAsset ingredient;
    [SerializeField]
    private EquipmentAsset equipment;
    
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(interactKey))
        {
            if (target == null)
                return;
          
            TableBox table = target.GetComponent<TableBox>();
            if (table != null)
            {
                table.Interact(ingredient, equipment, this);
            }

        }
    }
    
    public void SetIngredient(IngredientAsset c)
    {
        ingredient = c;

    }

    
    public void SetEquipment(EquipmentAsset t)
    {
        equipment = t;

    }

    
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (target != col.gameObject && target != null)
        {
            Deselect();
        }
        
        target = col.gameObject;
    
        }
    }
    
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject == target)
        {
            Deselect();
            target = null;
        }
    }
    
    void Deselect()
    {

    }
}
```

[Мой проект](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3b8ag26ketikqtu/Magical%20Madness%280.0.9%29.rar?dl=0).

***P.S.*** Мой меш в отличие от префаба "голый", как мне добавить к мешу остальные составляющие объекта с префаба? (текстурки, коллайдеры и т.д.)

Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: "Меш" - это, по сути, какой-то файл с какими-тол цифрами, ничего общего с "префабом" он не имеет.

Comment: Прикрепите значения transform'a WoodTable'а.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Добавил Трансформ Стола.

Comment: Проблема решена или есть какие-то вопросы?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Благодарю за вашу помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема исходит из непонимания, как работает преобразование значений transform'ов в parent-children отношении.

Возьмем пример в вакууме:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В вопросе предполагается, что самый "нижний" в иерархии ребенок будет иметь `Scale = (1, 1, 1)`, это абсолютно неправильно. **Локальный** `Scale` будет равен `(1, 1, 1)`, а вот **мировой** `Scale` будет равен `(0.5 * 0.25 * 1, 0.5 * 0.25 * 1, 0.5 * 0.25 * 1)`.

На самом деле там используются матрицы, но не будем перегружать вопрос этим, после матричных перемножений получим такой же результат, что я написал выше.

---

Смотрим ситуацию из вопроса:

```
Tables - Scale(1, 1, 1)
  \____Table - Scale(0.7, 0.7, 0.1)
   \     \____Overlay - Scale(1, 1, 1)
    \____Table - Scale(0.7, 0.7, 0.1)
     \     \____Overlay - Scale(1, 1, 1)
      \....
```

В итоге мировой `Scale` объекта `Overlay` после всех матричных преобразований будет равен: `(0.7, 0.7, 0.1)`, когда меш "Глаз", видимо, должна иметь `Scale = (1, 1, 1)`.

**Решить проблему можно 2 способами**:

1. Поменять `Scale` объекта `Overlay` так, чтобы он имел обратный эффект по сравнению со `Scale`'ом выше по иерархии, в данном случае, нужно выставить такие значения:

   ```
   (1/0.7, 1/0.7, 1/0.1) == (1.428, 1.428, 10)
   ```

   Такой способ имеет место быть, но тут мы встреваем во всякие неприятные округления и ограничения типа `float`. Да и выставлять все это каждый раз придется вручную, что неудобно, нудно и  приводит к ошибкам.
2. Изначально следить за `Scale`'ом и другими составляющими `Transform` в иерархии. В данном случае проще всего, на мой взгляд, сделать так:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   Т.е. просто разделить на "два лагеря" объекты с масштабом (1, 1, 1) и объекты с каким-то экзотическим масштабом.

---

Абсолютно такая же ситуация обстоит с Transform.position, только вместо умножения матриц там происходит сложение. Если вы внимательно посмотрите, то ваш `Overlay` сдвинут по оси `Z` на `4.63`, что и привело к сдвигу по оси `Z`.